# ANOVA for equivalence testing

Tags: r, repeated-measures, linear-model, post-hoc, equivalence

How to perform a ANOVA for statistical equivalence?

I read about the two one-sided test (TOST) for equivalence, but (I think) for this study design it is not possible to perform a classical t-test, so a repeated measures ANOVA is needed.

The study design is a common pre-post treatment-control design: there are two **different** groups (control / treatment) and **dependent** two measure points **at the baseline and a followup** (MP1 / MP2). The research question is, if the treatments are equal.

My thought is, that the ANOVA analyses the differences between the groups. Is there a post-hoc for equivalence, special in R?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to D_Williams, I read the [using-lsmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf) vignette and the [lsmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf) reference manual. There is a function called test. With this function you can do equivalence / noninferiority or nonsuperiority tests. Now I got stuck with a new problem. Because of the study design I need a linear regression with repeated measures. So here is a example dataset:

```
 dataset <- data.frame (ID    = rep(1:16),
                  GROUP = factor(rep(c("A","B"),8)),
                   MP1   = c(15,12,20,17,28,24,17,10,14,10,25,23,9,18,19,20),
                   MP2   = c(12,9,19,10,20,15,12,5,12,10,22,15,8,17,10,19),
                   )
```

The linear regression should be:

```
data.lm <- lm (MP2 - MP1 ~ GROUP, data=dataset)
```

As far as I understood this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35632/115148) right, Case 2b is the correct one for me. Because there are two quantitative variables and a one dichotomous variable.

Afterwards I run these commands:

```
library("lme4", "lsmeans", "estimablity")
data.lsm <- lsmeans(data.lm, "GROUP")
test(data.lsm, null = log(100), delta = 0.20, side="equivalence")
```

Delta is the equivalence margin or the range of similarity. But I am not sure what the log(100) is.

My questions are:

1. Is this approach right?

   and
2. To be honest: I don't really understand the last steps. Does anybody have some code example for studying them?

Comment: What are MP1 & MP2 ? Are the control and treatment group made by the same units?

Comment: MP1 and MP2 are the two dependent measure points at the beginning and at the end. The groups are not in the same unit.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by "equivalence" test? Are you interested in the mean/median values or on the entire distribution of MP1&MP2. Just to be sure I understood correctly, before answering to your question.

Comment: Usually you test for superiority with the H1 hypothesis testing. Here, the hypothesis H1 is, that the control treatment and the "new" treatment is equal. In this case I am interested in the mean / medians values.

Comment: @M.Unterreinter I think you are making confusion about H0 and H1 hypothesis. Typically, H0 is the equality hypothesis and H1 is the alternative, which can be uni or two-directional. In your case, I suspect, you have H0: old treatment = new treatment, H1: old treatment different from new treatment (or old treatment worse than new treatment ). Is that so?

Comment: Thank you really much, but no it isn't. The hypothesis are reversed and because of that I can't use the common methods. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3019319/) is a really good explanation. So I am looking for equivalence testing.

Comment: Ok now I see what do you mean. I'll write a full answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have only two groups, there is no need to perform an ANOVA. You can perform a TOST procedure by simply building a confidence interval (CI) for a two sample problem, say x and y, where  x = MP2-MP1 in the control group and y = MP2-MP1 in the treated group. You need to pay attention to the usual assumptions for the statistical tests: normality, heteroskedasticity, etc. But, once you have your CI, you can see if it is contained within the +-delta region or not. In R you can do something like this:

```
set.seed(12)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(70)

# for two sample t-test with equal variances
tt <- t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.90)

# for Welch two sample t-test
tt.uneq <- t.test(x, y, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.90)

# for two sample Wilcoxon test
wcox <- wilcox.test(x,y, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.90)

delta <- 0.32

library(plotrix)
plotCI(x = 1, y=diff(rev(tt$estimate)), ui = tt$conf.int[2], li = tt$conf.int[1],
       xlim=c(0,4), ylab = "Confidence intervals", ylim = c(-0.6, 0.6),
       xlab ="Methods")
plotCI(x = 2, y=diff(rev(tt.uneq$estimate)), ui = tt.uneq$conf.int[2],
       li = tt.uneq$conf.int[1], add=TRUE, col=2)
plotCI(x = 3, y=wcox$estimate, ui = wcox$conf.int[2],
       li = wcox$conf.int[1], add=TRUE, col=3)
abline(h = c(-delta, delta), lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Here, to illustrate the idea I'm considering three type of tests but there are many others in the literature. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you really much utobi. I thought that you can't use a t-test with repeated measurements and two groups because of the Type I error. Is it right, that with a CI there won't be this kind of error?

Comment: M.Unterreiner, the type I error rate is ubiquitous in statistical testing. Having said that, nothing special with repeated measures. In such a case, you have balanced samples so you can use either t.test or wilcox.test but you have to specify the option "paired=TRUE".

Comment: What if you also wanted to test that the increases (MP2-MP1) for each condition were significant? ie. MP2 was significantly different from MP1 in each condition. How would you test for all of these without inflating your Type-1 error rate?

Answer (score 3):

Generally equivalence testing is very limited to simple models. I have, however, recently learned that the  lsmeans package in r does equivalence testing for models more complex than a t-test. I have not used it, but I have used lsmeans and it is a very flexible tool. This might work, but you will have to check out the package vignette for the  details to be sure [see here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiyt8_P6aTQAhUhrFQKHYynAw8QFggrMAE&usg=AFQjCNFjodZgIINrQQctSYFcEf95PYZXew)

As of 2022, the `emmeans` package (successor to `lmmeans` can be used for equivalence tests of linear models; vignette info is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/confidence-intervals.html#equiv).